# How to handle Types in React and Express App?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

Im having a React client in the same project as my Node-Express backend. Right now my React app runs with TypeScript and I want to change my backend to TypeScript too.

Currently I have a `client` folder containing my React App and my server files just laying in my root directory.

Now since I'll be using TS on my server I'm asking myself how you handle Types in each projects. Right now for example I'm declaring a `interface` for component props like so:
App.tsx

```
export interface Room {
  gameId: string,
  started: boolean,
  players: string[]
}

function App() {
  const [room, setRoom] = useState<Room>();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Lobby room={room} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In Lobby.tsx.

```
import {Room} from "../App";

export interface LobbyProps {
  room: Room;
}

function Lobby(props: LobbyProps) {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <a href={'http://localhost:3000/' + props.room.gameId}>{'http://localhost:3000/' + props.room.started + " " + props.room.players}</a>
    </React.Fragment>
);
}

export default Lobby;
```

Already in my react App im reusing interfaces and my first question would be if it is okay to put those in a seperate file so I can use them from different places?

Second question would be what if have the same interfaces or types on my backend. Should I keep them on both sides or whats the best practise here?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: This [project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) has React app integrated with Express backend. I'm the author. There are some types/interfaces shared between backend and frontend using [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping), see `@backend`  in [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/client/tsconfig.json). This approach is by far the simplest when there are two projects involved in sharing.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to dump all interfaces into a dedicated interfaces.ts file and import them from there. On the other hand, if you have a specific interface type that would be used only in one module, it can stay right within this module.

Once you need some interfaces on the front-end, you can copy them from the back end, but usually, on the back end, you might have separate interfaces for ApiObject and DBObject, as you might not be passing the data from the DB as is. So you would probably copy just a part of the interfaces to your front end app (usually Api object interfaces).